# what is wrong with my code first migration?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

This is my migration and seeding code:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<AuthDb>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            ContextKey = "Service.DAL.AuthDb";
        }

    }
public class CreateOrRunMigrations: CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AuthDb>
    {
        public override void InitializeDatabase(AuthDb context)
        {
            base.InitializeDatabase(context);
            var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Migrations.Configuration());
            migrator.Update();

        }

        protected override void Seed(AuthDb context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

            // add Default product and company

        }

    }
```

The context is constructed this way

```
public class AuthDb : DbContext
    {
        public AuthDb() : base("name=xxx")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateOrRunMigrations());
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;            
            Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        }
   }
```

What I want is:

1. When the database is created first time, the seeding data is added.
2. When I make a change in the model, the migration code will apply the changes to the database automatically.

When I make a change (e.g. Company), and use update_database to add a migration in the console, the migration file was created. But when the code is run, I got an error complaining that my model and database doesn't match any more.

Of course it doesn't match as I just made a change and I was hoping that the migration will apply the change. However, it didn't. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your initializer derives from CreateDatabaseIfNotExists so it's only going to run when the database does not exist. Try making it derive from MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion:

```
public class CreateOrRunMigrations: MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AuthDb>
{

    // no need for InitializeDatabase override since that's what this initializer does...

    protected override void Seed(AuthDb context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);

        // add Default product and company

    }

}
```

Comment: If I change to MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion, what happens to seeding method? will it run every time the the model is updated?

Comment: Initializer seeds only run when the database is created. Migration seeds run every time you do update-database. So throw any seeding for a new database in the former, and any changes you make along the way in the latter. https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/